# Passing a variable through href - is it a good approach?

Tags: php, html, variables, href, backend

I'm currently working on my school project and I started wondering if it's a good approach to pass some variable through href so it can been seen in the URL. 
Is it good or a bad way and why?

Or are there any better ways?

Comment: I think using `localstorage` would be a better fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Script paths and query strings are used all the time. Just don't use them for anything sensitive.

Comment: Why would it be bad?  Sometimes you need to send a value to a URL.

Comment: for sensitive data don't use get, use post and you have to encode data while sending through get and decode it other side for safety

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu: And what specifically is the OP trying to do which would necessitate entirely different functionality like that?

Comment: Sometimes it's considered "best" practice. If you use it as a page counter or similar the page can be bookmarked. POST or other methods can not.

Comment: @AlivetoDie: `"for sensitive data dn't use get, use post"` - That's a bit misleading, don't you think?  POST is just as open as GET.  *Sensitive* data probably shouldn't be sent unencrypted over the wire *at all*.

Comment: @David for about 80-90% of internet users POST is magic. GET is very little less magic but still very hard to understand

Comment: @Andreas: Passing something off as "magic" and not attempting to understand it is also not a great way to treat "sensitive data".

Comment: That is not what I said. I'm just answering to your comment that POST is as open as GET.

Comment: Just wondering what's all the downvote about. Was the question really that bad?

Comment: It's quite clear that you have not tried to find the answer yourself before posting. A few minutes of browsing the web and you would have seen at least a handful of pages with method you ask about. And the question is opinion based. And there is no real error to fix, it's just a question about how... Well.. internet works.

Comment: @anthony: In general it's difficult to answer questions like "Is it bad to do X" when X is a perfectly reasonable technology that's used all the time.  We don't know what you're actually trying to implement or what factors are to be considered in your design.  You're basically asking, "I want to build something, is it a good idea to use a hammer?"  It's unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not information that should be private I don't see why you couldn't do it. Especially if you need to reference something on a new page, it would make things easier.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to use GET parameters for navigation purposes.

For user data input you can better use forms with POST.